# Calculate Prometheus request rate if it is some percent above or below request rate of the same timeframe some days ago

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to find a way to calculate in Prometheus if the Request Rate is 50% above the request rate of the same timeframe at the same day last week (-7d).
On what I have been reading until now, the rate function is only used to return the per second rate of requests over a period of time.

The following delta returns the difference of the requests from today and 7 days ago, but not the request rate:

```
delta(application:request{service=~"*"}[7d])
```

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus [rate()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) function calculates per second rate of increase of the time series *over a period of time*.
So first, you should select *a period of time* for the rate function, f.e.:
`application:request[5m]`. It's unlikely that you need a value of `[7d]` for a range interval because it means *"per-second rate over 7 days"*, you probably need something smaller, don't you?

When you get a valid range interval for **rate()**, next you want to compare the rates between the current value and the value 7 days ago.
The simplest way to do this is using [offset](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier):

`rate(application:request[5m]) - rate(application:request[5m] offset 7d)`

You can also use [delta()](https://demo_api_request_duration_seconds_count) for this, but it might apply extrapolation and requires passing a [range vector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-vectors) as a parameter, that in turn would require a [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/). Here is a possible example with a default [resolution/step](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/#subqueries) for subquery:

`delta(rate(application:request[5m])[7d:])`

There're some nuances on [delta() vs. subtract with offset](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/sysadmin/PrometheusDeltaVsOffsetII), that you should consider.

---

Also, you might find interesting these discussions:
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1772
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746